# How to embed an and operator inside a data.table function?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose we start with this dataframe generated by the code immediately beneath:

```
> data1
   ID Period Values_1 Values_2 State
1   1      1        5        5    X0
2   1      2        0        2    X1
3   1      3        0        0    X2
4   1      4        0       12    X1
5   2      1        1        2    X0
6   2      2       -1        0    X2
7   2      3        0        1    X0
8   2      4        0        0    X0
9   3      1        0        0    X2
10  3      2        0        0    X1
11  3      3        0        0    X9
12  3      4        0        2    X3
13  4      1        1        4    X2
14  4      2        2        5    X1
15  4      3        3        6    X9
16  4      4        0        0    X3

data1 <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    Values_1 = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0),
    Values_2 = c(5, 2, 0, 12, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X1","X0","X2","X0","X0", "X2","X1","X9","X3", "X2","X1","X9","X3")
  )
```

I've been using this data.table code to flag each ID with an "END" in State_1 when it no longer generates values in its future periods:

```
setDT(data1)[, State1 := ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1 + Values_2))), State, "END"), ID]
```

The above code gives these results:

```
> data1
    ID Period Values_1 Values_2 State State1
 1:  1      1        5        5    X0     X0
 2:  1      2        0        2    X1     X1
 3:  1      3        0        0    X2     X2
 4:  1      4        0       12    X1     X1
 5:  2      1        1        2    X0     X0
 6:  2      2       -1        0    X2    END
 7:  2      3        0        1    X0     X0
 8:  2      4        0        0    X0    END
 9:  3      1        0        0    X2     X2
10:  3      2        0        0    X1     X1
11:  3      3        0        0    X9     X9
12:  3      4        0        2    X3     X3
13:  4      1        1        4    X2     X2
14:  4      2        2        5    X1     X1
15:  4      3        3        6    X9     X9
16:  4      4        0        0    X3    END
```

When I would like to give these results for ID = 2 instead:

```
> data1
    ID Period Values_1 Values_2 State State1
 1:  1      1        5        5    X0     X0
 2:  1      2        0        2    X1     X1
 3:  1      3        0        0    X2     X2
 4:  1      4        0       12    X1     X1
 5:  2      1        1        2    X0     X0
 6:  2      2       -1        0    X2     X2
 7:  2      3        0        1    X0     X0
 8:  2      4        0        0    X0    END
 9:  3      1        0        0    X2     X2
10:  3      2        0        0    X1     X1
11:  3      3        0        0    X9     X9
12:  3      4        0        2    X3     X3
13:  4      1        1        4    X2     X2
14:  4      2        2        5    X1     X1
15:  4      3        3        6    X9     X9
16:  4      4        0        0    X3    END
```

In order to do this, I need to change the data.table code to in effect something like the below (it doesn't work), where if BOTH the future period values for an ID of Values_1 AND Values_2 (separately calculated) = 0, then the State_1 for that ID is flagged END for all of its future periods. How can this be done in data.table?

```
setDT(data1)[, State1 := ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1))) & rev(cumsum(rev(Values_2))), State, "END"), ID]
```

This is linked with related post [How to use dplyr or data.table to perform look-ahead calculations by groups of data subsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72231745/how-to-use-dplyr-or-data-table-to-perform-look-ahead-calculations-by-groups-of-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
f <- function(v1,v2,s) {
  s[cumsum(abs(v1)+abs(v2))==0] <- "END"
  s
}

setDT(data1)[order(-Period), State1:=f(Values_1, Values_2, State), by=ID]
```

Output:

```
    ID Period Values_1 Values_2 State State1
 1:  1      1        5        5    X0     X0
 2:  1      2        0        2    X1     X1
 3:  1      3        0        0    X2     X2
 4:  1      4        0       12    X1     X1
 5:  2      1        1        2    X0     X0
 6:  2      2       -1        0    X2     X2
 7:  2      3        0        1    X0     X0
 8:  2      4        0        0    X0    END
 9:  3      1        0        0    X2     X2
10:  3      2        0        0    X1     X1
11:  3      3        0        0    X9     X9
12:  3      4        0        2    X3     X3
13:  4      1        1        4    X2     X2
14:  4      2        2        5    X1     X1
15:  4      3        3        6    X9     X9
16:  4      4        0        0    X3    END
```

Comment: Note that when run against complete data of 2mm+ rows this is significantly faster than setDT(data1)[, State1 := ifelse(rev(cumsum(abs(rev(Values_1 + Values_2)))), State, "END"), ID]. I wonder why?

Comment: the single ordering of `-Period` probably helps quite a bit, rather than the rev/rev combination..

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the linked post appears to be assuming non-negative values for `Values_1` and `Values_2`. If there are negatives, insert an `abs` into the `data.table` expression:

```
setDT(data1)[, State1 := ifelse(rev(cumsum(rev(Values_1 | Values_2))), State, "END"), ID]
```

Comment: In the actual data this little data.table snippet is used in, there are actual legitimate negative values that must remain. So I can't use abs() at least in this context. Instead, I'm trying to run the equivalent of cumsum(rev(Values_1)) and cumsum(rev(values_2)) and if they are both negative, then flag with "END".

Comment: Based on the example, it appears that `State1` is to be set to `END` if the the reverse cumulative sum of `Values_1` and `Values_2` are both `0`. Is it supposed to be set to `END` if they are both negative? What if one is negative and the other is zero?

Comment: The `abs` won't modify `Values_1` or `Values_2`, it will just keep the negatives from confusing the logic for detecting trailing streams of only zeros. It might help to clarify things if you could provide an example where this answer doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: Sorry jblood94 for the confusion. Your answer works perfectly. Basically, State_1 should be set to "END" in the period, for a given ID, when both Value_1 and Value_2 are all 0's for that period and for all remaining periods.

Comment: This is a nice solution too. However, I'm just wondering about the `abs(rev(Values1 + Values_2))`.. If both Values_1 equal -Values_2, you could have a problem here.. That is, if Row 6 Values_2  was -1 and Row 7 Values_1 was -1, I think the desired output would still be to have "END" only in row 8 for id=2; however, this solution would give "END" for rows 6,7,and 8 for id=2

Comment: @langtang, you are correct. Better to skip `abs` and use `|`. See corrected answer.